# I updated the branch of a pull request from upstream/master. Will it pollute the pull request if I push the branch again to github?

Tags: git, github, branch, push, pull-request

I forked a project, created a feature branch, implemented the feature and sent a pull request. While waiting for the answer I updated my local code from upstream and now I'm wondering  if I later have to add more things to my feature branch and push it again to github will the pulled in upstream changes also appear in the pull request? Or github is clever enough not to show those changes in the pull request commits, because those changes already exist in upstream?

I'm asking because now the commits in the pull request are clean and it would make the pull request harder to read if unrelated changes also appeared in it.

Comment: I've never done this, but I doubt GitHub would be that stupid. Most probably it is the commit for which you have sent a pull request, not the name of the branch.

Comment: @Shahbaz if you go to a pull request page on github then at the bottom it says if you add further commits to the branch from which the pull request is originated then those commits will appear in the pull request. This is how a pull request can be updated with new code if the upstream developer requires further changes before merging it. The question is will the upstream changes I pulled in ater sending the pull request also appear as commits in the pull request if I push new code to the feature branch?

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. So if you already know that the changes will be added to the pull request, what's your question then?

Comment: Is github clever enough not to show those changes in the pull request which came from upstream if I push new changes onto the feature branch? That is the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you merge in changes from the target repository, the merge commit itself will be shown but the commits that are already in the target repository will not be shown.

Here's an [example pull request](https://github.com/aschrab/lsm/pull/1) which was created with only the first commit shown.